# Why are my UI elements not resetting correctly after being animated/scaled off screen?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, modal-dialog, segue

So I'll give as much information about this project as I can right up front. Here is an image of a section of the storyboard that is relevant to the issue:

[image]

And here is the flow of the code:

**1)** A user plays the game. This scrambles up the emoji that are displayed and will eventually hide all of the emoji on the right side.

**2)** When someone wins the game, it calls

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowWinScreenSegue", sender: self)
```

Which will perform the segue the red arrow is pointing to. This segue is a modal segue, over current content, cross dissolve.

**3)** Stuff goes on here, and then I try to get back to the game screen so the user can play another game. Here is my current code for that

```
// self.delegate is the GameController that called the segue
// it's set somewhere else in the code so I can call these reset functions
GameController.gs = GameState()
guard let d = self.delegate else {
    return
}
d.resetGameToMatchState()

dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    print("Modal dismiss completed")
    GameController.gs = GameState()
    self.delegate?.resetGameToMatchState()
})
```

So here's where the issue is. You can see that I have to call `delegate?.resetGameToMatchState()` twice for anything to actually happen. If I remove the top one, nothing happens when I call the second one and vice-versa. What makes this so annoying is that the user will see a weird jump where all the ui goes from the old state to the new state because it's updating so late and spastically.

**What I've tried so far**
So this whole issue has made me really confused on how the UI system works.

My first thought was that maybe the function is trying to update the UI in a thread that's executing too early for the UI thread. So I put the whole body of `resetGameToMatchState` in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` call. This didn't do anything.

Then I thought that it was working before because when the WinScreenSegue was being dismissed before (when it was a "show" segue) it was calling `GameController`'s `ViewDidAppear`. I tried manually calling this function in the dismiss callback, but that didn't work either and feels really hacky.

And now I'm stuck :( Any help would be totally appreciated. Even if it's just a little info that can clear up how the UI system works.

Here is my resetGameToMatchState():

```
//reset all emoji labels
    func resetGameToMatchState() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let tier = GameController.gs.tier

            var i = 0
            for emoji in self.currentEmojiLabels! {
                    emoji.frame = self.currentEmojiLabelInitFrames[i]
                    emoji.isHidden = false
                    emoji.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1);
                    i+=1
            }

            i=0
            for emoji in self.goalEmojiLabels! {
                emoji.frame = self.goalEmojiLabelInitFrames[i]
                emoji.isHidden = false
                emoji.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1);
                i+=1
            }

            //match state
            for i in 1...4 {
                if GameController.gs.currentEmojis[i] == GameController.gs.goalEmojis[i] {
                    self.currentEmojiLabels?.findByTag(tag: i)?.isHidden = true
                }
            }

            //reset highlight
            let f = self.highlightBarInitFrame
            let currentLabel = self.goalEmojiLabels?.findByTag(tag: tier)
            let newSize = CGRect(x: f.origin.x, y: (currentLabel?.frame.origin.y)!, width: f.width, height: (currentLabel?.frame.height)! )
            self.highlightBarImageView.frame = newSize

            //update taps
            self.updateTapUI()

            //update goal and current emojis to show what the current goal/current selected emoji is
            self.updateGoalEmojiLabels()
            self.updateCurrentEmojiLabels()

        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
So I just found this out. The only thing that isn't working when I try to reset the UI is resetting the right side emoji to their original positions. What I do is at the start of the app (in viewDidLoad) I run this:

```
for emoji in currentEmojiLabels! {
    currentEmojiLabelInitFrames.append(emoji.frame)
}
```

This saves their original positions to be used later. I do this because I animate them to the side of the screen before hiding them.
Now when I want to reset their positions, I do this:

```
var i = 0
for emoji in self.currentEmojiLabels! {
        emoji.frame = self.currentEmojiLabelInitFrames[i]
        emoji.isHidden = false
        emoji.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1);
        i+=1
 }
```

this should set them all to their original frame and scale, but it doesn't set the position correctly. It DOES reset the scale though. What's weird is that I can see a tiny bit of one of the emoji off to the left of the screen and when they animate, they animate from far off on the left. I'm trying to think of why the frames are so off...

**UPDATE 2**
So I tried changing the frame reset code to this:

```
emoji.frame = CGRect(x: 25, y: 25, width: 25, height: 25)
```

Which I thought should reset them correctly to the top left, but it STILL shoves them off to the left. This should prove that the currentEmojiLabelInitFrames are not the issue and that it has something to do with when I'm setting them. *Maybe the constraints are getting reset or messed up?*

Comment: `self.delegate?` must be nil after vc dismissed.

Comment: Why are you assigning a new instance of `GameState` each time?  What does the delegate method do?  What does `viewWill/DidAppear` do in the first VC?

Comment: @Ryan What do you mean? I should set it to nil?

Comment: When you call `self.delegate?.resetGameToMatchState()` in the dismiss completion closure, can you check `self.delegate` is not nil?

Comment: @Paulw11 I assign a new instance because the initializer creates a new random state for the game. So instead of calling a function to re-randomize it I just initialize a new instance. And ViewWill/DidAppear updates all of the UI. It updates the emoji to match the gameState, the coin labels, timer label etc.

Comment: @Ryan I just updated the code, same result though. I did make a little bit of progress though, I'll put it in an edit right now.

Comment: You should never call the `viewDid...` `viewWil...` methods directly. Can you edit your question to show the `resetGameToMatchState()` code ?

Comment: Also, what triggers the dismiss code you have shown?  Is it a timer? Is that timer running on the main queue?

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't call viewDid/Will anymore, I just tested it once, I thought it might be bad practice haha. And yeah I'll add that above my update. I just threw some snippets in the update too. It's a timer, I'm not sure if it's running on the main queue (I don't really understand how that works) but it's initialized in viewDidLoad so it should be.

Comment: @Paulw11 I just figured it out, I'm posting an answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your first screen, `GameController`, should receive a `viewWillAppear` callback from UIKit when the modal `WinScreenController` is being dismissed.

So its `resetGameToMatchState` function could simply set a property to `true`, then your existing `resetGameToMatchState` could move into `viewWillAppear`, checking first if the property is being set.

```
var resetNeeded: Bool = false

func resetGameToMatchState() {
  resetNeeded = true
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // reset code here
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but viewWillAppear doesn't get called when the segue is dismissed. I think it's because of the fact that its an overlay, so technically its visible the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; Reset an element's scale BEFORE resetting it's frame or else it will scale/position incorrectly

Finally figured this out. Here's a bit more background. When an emoji is animated off the screen, this is called:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {
    let newFrame = self.profileButton.frame
    prevLabel?.frame = newFrame
    prevLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1);
})  { (finished) in
    prevLabel?.isHidden = true
}
```

So this sets the frame to the top left of the screen and then scales it down. What I didn't realize is that when I want to reset the element, I NEED to set the scale back to normal before setting the frame. Here is the new reset code:

```
for emoji in self.currentEmojiLabels! {
    emoji.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1) //this needs to be first
    emoji.frame = self.currentEmojiLabelInitFrames[i] //this needs to be after the scale
    emoji.isHidden = false
    i+=1
}
```